# How to download a file at an url that returns a "206 Partial Content" response?

Tags: firefox, download, http-status-codes

Let's say that I'm listening to an audio file online by pointing my web browser to some url `https://someurl.fr/file.oga`.
So the file isn't embedded in a page, but is accessed directly by the browser.
Usually, I could then download that file with Ctrl+S or "Save as".
But when I do that, I end up with a local file that plays fine, but only contains about 5mn out of the 30mn that I can listen to online.
And that's the better case, using Firefox. With Chromium, saving the file locally fails entirely. Using curl, I also get only the first 5mn of the audio.

Upon closer inspection, it appears that the url doesn't return an HTTP status "200 OK", but rather "206 Partial Content", which I guess is the cause of my issue.

Since I'm still able to listen to the whole file online, I would imagine that there is some way to download it entirely, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the popular tool `curl` to do this. curl handles servers which respond with 206 Partial Content seemlessly.

For example:

```
curl https://example.com/mylargevideofile.mp4 -o /dev/null
```

Just works

Comment: Is that a new feature? As indicated in my question, at the time curl did not download the whole content. (The website that that I had in mind has since closed, so I can't test.)